# Conditionally Use Lock in the Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a method which is being used by multi-thread. In the method, there are some critical codes that I have to use lock to allow only ONE thread to access it. So, the code looks like:

```
private void RunCode()
{
    ......  // some other codes
    lock (myLock)
    {
        ......  // critical code01
    }

    ......  // some other codes

    lock (myLock)
    {
        ......  // critical code02
    }

    ....... // some other codes
}
```

This code is being used by multi-thread. Now, because of some workflow changes, we want to keep the code run as it is, BUT in some special cases, we want to run the critical codes immediately without the lock. We are ok even if the calculation result is not 100% correct because we do not lock it. So, the code should look like:

```
private void RunCode(bool isSpecial)
{
    ......  // some other codes
    lock (myLock)   // if isSpecial == true, do not lock it, otherwise, lock it
    {
        ......  // critical code01
    }

    ......  // some other codes

    lock (myLock)   // if isSpecial == true, do not lock it, otherwise, lock it
    {
        ......  // critical code02
    }

    ....... // some other codes
}
```

Based on research, it seems we have to do something like

```
if (isSpecial)
{
    ......  // critical code01

}
else
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
        ......  // critical code01
    }
}
```

It will work, but the issue is that we have to repeat the critical code01 (and code02) twice. And these codes are pretty complex and closely related with other codes in the RunCode() method.

My question is: is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions? We are using c# .net, but any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Considering you have code that doesn't work, and could do *just about anything* when it runs, a bit of repetition is the *least* of your worries.

Comment: You can wrap your critical code in a method as well so that the repetition becomes reusability.

Comment: If you don't care whether your code is returning the correct result, why not save you all the hard coding and return `17.549`? It's wrong... but hey, at least it did not lock anything...

Comment: You should be looking to use some other synchronization method then, like [`Semaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would look at refactoring the code so you can separate the critical sections into different methods. It may mean more pain now but should prove it's worth in the long run.

Comment: @RonBeyer How is that any better than `lock`?

Comment: @Servy Because you can do `if (special) semaphore.WaitOne()`, the `lock` because it is a code-block, can't be conditionally run the same way without duplicating code.

Comment: @RonBeyer Considering it's a thing that it's literally never appropriate to do, that's not actually a concern.  Also, still not a reason to use a `Semaphore`.  If you just want to call a method rather than using the correct code block for it, you can just use `Monitor`, which is what `lock` is calling under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Try use a `Monitor` class directly. It has a method [`TryEnter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbdx9xx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
Rewrite your code like this:

```
try
{
    if (isSpecialCase || Monitor.TryEnter(myLock, TimeSpan.MaxValue))
    {
        // critical code01
    }
}
finally
{
    if (!isSpecialCase)
    {
        // lock was taken
        Monitor.Exit(myLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your try-finally should be inside the `if`, not outside.  See the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbdx9xx(v=vs.110).aspx  Notice in the example that the `TryEnter` is outside of a try-catch block.

Comment: since lock actually runs Monitor.TryEnter, I have one question. It seems 'lock' always lock it, but it seems TryEnter does not ensure this. Is this the reason why use TimeSpan,MaxValue?

Comment: @user2023861 In msdn example we are go into `if` branch only when a  lock is taken. In my answer we can enter "critical code01" whithout lock.

Comment: @urlreader actually a `lock` runs `Monitor.Enter`. But you are right: `TryEnter` with infinite timeout works exactly as `Enter`

Comment: @AleksAndreev, that's not my point.  Of course you can modify the MSDN example to use the `isSpecialCase` check.  My point is that your code does a `try` and then an `if`.  The MSDN example does an `if` and then a `try`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do sounds pretty strange to say the least. But if I could not live without it, I would try defining a lambda expression on the fly and call that in these two locations. Something along the lines of

```
int aNumber = 5;

Action criticalCode01 = () => {Console.WriteLine("Foo! (repeat "+aNumber+" times)");};

if (isSpecial)
{
    criticalCode01();
}
else
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
        criticalCode01();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
try
{
    if (!isSpecialCase) Monitor.Enter(myLock);

    // critical code01
}
finally
{
    if (!isSpecialCase) Monitor.Exit(myLock);
}
```